# How to implement MICE in data imputation using sklearn IterativeImputer?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-imputation, mice

I'm interested in learning how to implement MICE in imputing missing values in  my datasets. I'd like to use sklearn IterativeImputer for the following reason (source from sklearn docs):

> Our implementation of IterativeImputer was inspired by the R MICE
> package (Multivariate Imputation by Chained Equations) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ffVe.png), but
> differs from it by returning a single imputation instead of multiple
> imputations. However, IterativeImputer can also be used for multiple
> imputations by applying it repeatedly to the same dataset with
> different random seeds when sample_posterior=True

I had asked for an example on stack overflow and received the following response from @Stanislas Morbieu (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58613108/imputing-missing-values-using-sklearn-iterativeimputer-class-for-mice/58615845?noredirect=1#comment103542017_58615845)

Using the following diagram and the example provided by stack overflow, how do I pool together the results from the different imputation sets? I would appreciate example code to show how to do this step-by-step. Thanks!

Image Source: https://laptrinhx.com/handling-missing-values-in-machine-learning-part-2-345847522/

[image]